# Find the shortest unique string within a text at a given position

Tags: indexing, hash, lookup, text-analysis

What other techniques are there for finding the shortest string, unique within a `text`, at a determined `position`, other than brute force by incrementally adding characters to the character at `position` and checking for uniqueness?

To better explain,

```
text = "word1 word2 word3"
```

If `position = 9` (r in word2); `shortest_unique_at_pos = "rd2"`.

Small observation, if `position = 13` (w in word3); the resulting string should be searched in both directions, so `shortest_unique_at_pos = "2 w"`, not `"word3"`. Applying some techniques while alternating directions would yield the desired result, of course.

Comment: Give more formal definition of "unique string"

Comment: That was very politely put @Dmitry. I would say "What???"

Comment: that the resulting string doesn't appear more than once within the text?

Comment: @jamima The *determined position* makes it confusing, not the *unique string*

Comment: *determined position* = `r` in `word2`

Comment: Give us the code you have tried, an input example, and the desired output. What you describe is unclear.

Comment: What are you expecting is not clear? Btw you tagged many languages? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I will come through like an ass, and most certainly am, but I believe that the answer is quite obvious, although inefficient. That's why I don't provide any example code. I didn't mention the most intuitive solution, though

Comment: @jamima You say yourself, it hasn't much to do with language, so I'ld remove those tags. Nice hard problem btw., no idea at the moment here. And you're right, the brute-force solution is obvious, no need to add code. It wouldn't help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume that the brute force approach you are trying to avoid is involves multiple iterations over the "body of text" for every unique string. It is possible to solve this with an upfront cost of `O(n)` where `n` is the length of the text and then each time you search for shortest unique string `O(m*k)` where `m` is the length of the "unique string" and `k` is the number of times the letter at "determined index" appears in the text. This may be beneficial if you regularly search for short unique strings in large texts.

You can create a dictionary in advance where the keys are letters in the "body of text" and values are sets with indexes where these letters can be found in the text. For example a python dictionary would look like this:

```
indexes = { 'w': {0, 6, 12}, 'o': {1, 7, 13}, 'r': {2, 8, 14} }
```

Creating such a dictionary is an `O(n)` operation. It's probably more complicated as memory is (re)allocated and data is copied and you get hash collisions but basically you go through the text once and add the index of a letter at the corresponding index set. You do the above once per "body of text" and reuse each time you search for shortest unique string.

When you are given a "determined index" e.g. `2` to start searching from:

1. get the letter at the current index `i`. e.g. `'r'`
2. copy the set of indexes for that letter to set `s` e.g. `{2, 8, 14}`
3. remove `i` from `s` e.g `{8, 14}`
4. increment all indexes (+1) in `s` e.g. `{9, 15}`
5. get the next letter after `i`. e.g. `'d'`
6. get the index set `ns` for the next letter
7. if `s` and `ns` are not equal stop you have found the shortest unique string
8. if `s` and `ns` are equal repeat from step 4

Complexity is proportional to the length of the resulting string due to the iteration between steps 4 - 8. It's also proportional to the size of `s` which is equal to the frequency of the letter where you start from in the text. Comparing 2 sets for equality has complexity proportional to the size of the smallest set.

Mind the trade-offs when looking for more efficient algorithms. The brute force may actually be better for short texts. The above approach has an upfront cost that may not make sense if you only search once. Also, it requires extra memory.